# Is it possible to persist linux session between reboots?

Tags: linux-mint, session, hibernate, persistence

I use Linux Mint 17.3 x64. 
Is it possible to make linux remember state of all opened applications and terminals so after shutdown/restart of my machine, all mentioned would open in same position and state?

Does it make difference if I dual-boot Windows (two physically different disks) and persist that state between using Windows/Linux?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is hibernation, which is categorically separate from shutting down and restarting. However, it does allow you to power the machine down completely and to boot a dual-boot OS in the interim, without losing any local state.

Comment: @TomHunt I've actually disabled hibernation completely, because I've read that it's really REALLY not recommended as linux shouldn't be hibernated at all. It was official tutorial on mints site, i think. 
I believe earlier releases od ubuntu/mint had something like session persistance butit was disabled. I want it back :(

Comment: The kernel and all major window managers support hibernation quite well for many years now; just try it. I can't believe that any halfway recent distri would be an exception here and I guess you misunderstood something.

Comment: I use hibernation routinely; it's how I access my dual-boot. Either the information is outdated, or Mint is. (I don't really recommend Mint anyway; my distro is Arch, which supports hibernation without any difficulty at all.)

Comment: There's no reason not to use hibernation. A decade ago it was often buggy, but these days it pretty much just works. A statement like “Linux shouldn't be hibernated” is hogwash.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used hibernation, but at that time Grub 1 wouldn't offer its menu when Linux was hibernated, and automatically booted/woke up Linux. Is there a setting for this, or is this a "feature" of Grub 1, or is this a past problem that disappeared nowadays?